# MYSQL: count filtered rows with having

Tags: mysql, count, having

There is two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE `products` (
`id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`price` decimal(10,2) unsigned NOT NULL,
`quantity` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL,
`name` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `products_item` (
`id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`product_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
`quantity` smallint(6) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

and basic query that return some rows

```
select p.id, p.quantity, sum(pi.quantity) as pi_quantity
from products p
left join products_item pi on pi.product_id=p.id
group by p.id
having p.quantity > sum(pi.quantity)
```

How can I count the number of product rows per `p.id`?

Thanks.

Comment: count of what rows?, please provide expected result

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Do you mean per-id count, or a count of the total number of rows?

Comment: You want to count the number of your result rows? You can always select from a query and count: `select count(*) from (<your query here>) x`.

Comment: @Barmar, yes I want count of rows per p.id.

Comment: @Barmar, then I get "Unknown column 'p.quantity' in 'having clause'" :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add `COUNT(pi.id)` to the query.

```
select p.id, p.quantity AS quantity, sum(pi.quantity) as pi_quantity, COUNT(pi.id) AS pi_count
from products p
left join products_item pi on pi.product_id=p.id
group by p.id
having quantity > pi_quantity
```

You can also refer to the alias in the `HAVING` clause.